# Specify a github url for a dependency in a cabal file

Tags: haskell, hdbc

The HDBC-mysql package is currently broken for me. The fix is in [this fork](https://github.com/markus7/hdbc-mysql). How can I specify that I want cabal to build from this fork of HDBC-mysql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to get stuff up and running, just checkout and build manually.

```
> git clone https://github.com/markus7/hdbc-mysql.git
> cd hdbc-mysql
> cabal install
```

This should keep things working until the new changes have been pushed to Hackage.

(note- It is possible that you will have to fiddle with dependencies to get the project to use this version....  But I would just try the simple install first and see if it works).

Comment: After I did this, I had to run `cabal sandbox add-source hdbc-mysql/` to tell the sandbox to use this package. Here `hdbc-mysql` is the path to the directory containing the built package.